# Elasticsearch 5.2 unit tests

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, elasticsearch, client

I am writing unit tests for ES5.2, and am having some issues. I need to create a client which connects to a local node for running tests, so I use

```
esClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```

This causes problems

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: running tests but failed to invoke RandomizedContext#getRandom
```

So then I used an annotation on my unit test classes as

```
@RunWith(com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.class)
```

but this gave me an error

```
SEVERE: 2 threads leaked from TEST scope at {method_name}): 
1) Thread[id=36, name={project_name}writer-thread-0, state=WAITING, group={project_name}-writer]
```

And the unit tests threw errors as

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue
```

I tried to use the annotation as below on the unit test class

```
@ThreadLeakScope(ThreadLeakScope.Scope.NONE)
```

That got rid of some error messages, but there were still concurrency issues in the code.
Anyone knows how to handle this? Is there some explicit thread safety methods I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Excluding `com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting:randomizedtesting-runner` from dependencies works.

Example (build.gradle):

```
dependencies {
    testCompile(project(path:':other-project')) {
        exclude  group:"com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting", module:"randomizedtesting-runner"
    }
}
```

---

Why?

If you have `randomizedtesting-runner` in your classpath, ES will load it:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.10/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/Randomness.java#L55

And use it:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.10/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/Randomness.java#L102